# Add Donchian channels to weekly and monthly charts

Tags: r, quantmod, stock

I use following code to create Donchian channels for daily charts:

```
lag(DonchianChannel(cbind(Hi(XXX), Lo(XXX))))
```

And add it to the plot using `addTA`

How can I add Donchian channels to weekly and monthly charts? (essentially where weeks and months are treated as days). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect it to be any different depending on the periodicity of the data in `XXX`. What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a Donchian Channel for the weekly chart of MSFT shares:

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
my_quote <- getSymbols("MSFT", auto.assign = FALSE)
my_quote_w <- to.weekly(my_quote)
dc <- lag(DonchianChannel(my_quote_w[,c("my_quote.High", "my_quote.Low")]))
candleChart(my_quote_w,col=TRUE,theme=chartTheme('white'),
        subset='last 3 years', log.scale=TRUE, name="MSFT-weekly")
plot(addTA(dc$high, on=1, col='red'))
plot(addTA(dc$low, on=1, col='blue'))
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot. If I want to make it more or less sensitive, typically the four-week average for a daily chart is changed to two weeks for more sensitive and eight weeks for less sensitive. How can this be done for weekly / monthly charts?

Comment: The straightforward way to change the sensitivity is to vary the value of `n` as described in `?TTR::DonchianChannel`. Beyond that, I'm not sure I can help here. The expert in this is @JoshuaUlrich . He developed the fantastic `TTR` package, which includes the `DonchianChannel()` function.

Comment: In `DonchianChannel` the `n` parameter defaults to 10, meaning it gets the high and low from the last 10 periods. So, increase `n` to make it less sensitive.

Comment: I see. n=10 means 10 business days, in other words 2 weeks. So the corresponding sensitivity for weekly charts would be n=14. Thanks!!

Comment: @Oposum What you describe is correct for daily candles/bars. In general `n` refers to units of time in the series. Here we have already converted the data to weekly values (using `to.weekly()`), and each candle represents one week. Hence, in this case, the default `n=10` refers to 10 weeks.

Comment: Of course, I was just meaning that for weekly plots n should be multiples of 7 as far as I understand. For daily charts, there are 5 trading days in a week, so it n would be multiples of 5.

Comment: @Opsum In weekly plots `n` should be chosen according to the numbers of weeks you want to look back to determine the high / low in the Donchian Channel. I don't see why those should be multiples of 7. The variable `n` refers to the time unit used in the time series, which is not necessarily trading days. In fact, in this case n=1 is refers to one week; i.e., 5 trading sessions (neglecting possible holidays).